# automatic and efficient image cropping with saliency map in opencv

Tags: image-processing, opencv

currently i worked on a automatic image cropping-algorithm which based on a saliency map.

The idea is, that the user can set up some parameters, to set up the size of the new image and the algorithm searching the optimal rect with a maximum of saliency.

Can someone help me to find the optimal rectangle with a maximum of saliency efficiently?
greetings

Comment: my problem is to find the rectangle with the maximal saliency in a efficient way

Comment: You still need to define the problem better.  Images would help.  As you have asked it right now, a solution could be to draw your rectangle around the single pixel with highest saliency, that would maximize the average saliency inside the rectangle.

Comment: define "optimal", wrt your saliency map and rectangle dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In time I'm useing the `NelderMead` to solve the minimization-problem.
This works quite good i think.